# Intercepting app HTTP requests

Tags: networking, proxy, bluestacks

I wanted to be able to intercept HTTP/HTTPS requests in apps on Android. I figured the best way to do this was with Bluestacks and Proxycap. But when I configured both of them together, it still didn't intercept app requests. Does anyone have any idea how I could achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue for a while. Finally, found a way out to track traffic coming from the emulator. You can start the emulator using:

`emulator -avd <emuName> -http-proxy http://<SYSTEM_IP>:<PORT>`

where emuName should be replaced with your emulator instance's name; SYSTEM_IP should be replaced with your system's IP address and PORT should be the port where the interceptor is running.

You can take a look at this: 
http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/04/intercept-http-requests-sent-from-app.html.
Hope it helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.